# A simple JSON to XML conversion without investment in servers?

Tags: xml, json, rss, feed, yql

Im a complete beginner with code and api calls so be gentle.

Im trying to create a twitter account that automatically populates with the most popular youtube video, flickr photo and news article globally every day.

The news api im using spits data out in JSON. I need this in XML. Ive looked into YQL to perform the conversion however when I replicate code examples using the api call I've constructed I have no luck.

**Can anyone recommend a simple means of converting JSON to XML without investment in servers?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StAXON](https://github.com/beckchr/staxon) to convert JSON to XML, see the [Converting JSON to XML](https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Converting-JSON-to-XML) wiki page.